# How do I create an extension to allow an array of a custom type to conform to a protocol?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-protocols

I have a custom type `Banana` and I would like to create an extension of `Array` (or, If I have to, `Sequence`) of `Banana` to conform to the protocol `CustomStringConvertible` so that calling `description` on the array of `Banana` would return "A bunch of bananas". Is this possible and, if so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Look like you have to wait until Swift 4. What you described sounds like [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md)

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to override Array to String casting in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39046816/2976878)

Comment: @CodeDifferent That looks good, but I can already extend a `Sequence` with an element type like this `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Banana { ... }`. I would just like to have the resulting sequence conform to `CustomStringConvertible` or is this actually the same proposal you mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You can constrain an extension, but a constrained extension can't contain an inheritance clause (the [Swift proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) @Code Different linked above is exactly what you're looking for).

One workaround would be to make the constrained extension, but just add your own property, rather than having it conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.

```
class Banana : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "a banana"
    }
}

let aBanana = Banana()
aBanana.description // "a banana"

extension Array where Element: Banana {
    var bananaDescription: String {
        return "a bunch of bananas"
    }
}

let bananas = [Banana(), Banana(), Banana()]
bananas.bananaDescription // "a bunch of bananas"
```

Worth noting, too, that `Array` already conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`.

```
let bananas = [Banana(), Banana(), Banana()]
bananas.description // "[a banana, a banana, a banana]"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a custom method in your banana class, printDescription, which would print your desired description. No need to create the extension in this case.

Comment: I've already got that for a single banana (which does conform to CustomStringConvertable, and the property's just called description), but I wanted to print about the collection of bananas, not just each banana.